# Wordpress shortcode for wp_list_categories()

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to list all the categories in a page. I tried doing it but I'm not that professional, and I kept getting error on functions.php.

thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look into Justin Tadlock’s WordPress Plugin ›[Template Tag Shortcodes](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/24/template-tag-shortcodes-wordpress-plugin)‹.

Answer (score 2):

That´s true. If you use the shortcode in a widget/sidebar, the category-list will appear in weird places. To prevent this behavior, just add echo=0 to wp_list_categories(). For the example above this would be:

```
wp_list_categories("echo=0&orderby=name&include=3,5,9,16")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  By echoing it, you can put this in your shortcode where you are 'returning' the content.  I edited above with a more complete block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Wordpress docs for wp_list_categories: [Template Tags/wp list categories « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

There are lots of parameters, and a basic example from the page linked above is:

> To sort categories alphabetically and include only the categories with
>   IDs of 16, 3, 9 and 5, you could write the following code:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5,9,16'); ?> 
</ul>
```

That gives you the basic function. To turn that into a shortcode, do this in the theme's functions.php file:

```
function my_wp_list_categories_shortcode() {
   return '<ul>' . wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5,9,16') . '<ul>' ; }

add_shortcode( 'list_my_categories_with_this_shortcode', 'my_wp_list_categories_shortcode' );
```

The shortcode you add via the WordPress editor is `[list_my_categories_with_this_shortcode]`

Comment: This won't work. wp_list_categories() will echo before <ul> inside of a function.